# Vim rename variable

Tags: vim

Most people say vim is greatest editor.

But is there any way to rename variable as fast as sublime.

Example:

```
function f($items) {
    $items;
    ....
    $items;
}
```

In sublime:

1. Go to items variable
2. click ctrl+d 2 times
3. rename variable

In VIM:

1. Search for /items
2. cw
3. write the new name
4. "n" for next occurrence and then "." to repeat

In vim obviously the keystrokes are more.

Does anyone knows easier and faster rename variable method?

Thank you

Comment: `:%s/items/new name/g`

Comment: I forgot to mention i doesnt want to replace the whole file. Just in this function

Comment: If you are coding in C or C++, you can try using the `clang-refactor` plugin.

Comment: Thanks, last question - can i use %s replace command but only in selection (visual mode)

Comment: yes, of course, visual select function body with `vi{` then do replace: `:'<,'>s/items/new name/`

Comment: @dNitro I assume that is supposed to select the current function, but it should be noted you'd need to have your cursor in the right scope so it doesn't just select, say, an if-block.  Also I don't think it would select the arguments of the function even if the cursor is properly placed.

Comment: But how can i search in all project files. Grep doesnt work I am on windows

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, Yep, but that was fastest visual select which comes to my mind! of course someone could place the cursor on the opening curly brace of function then `V%` will select entire function (including arguments) and then do replace.

Comment: In sublime, is there a way of doing it without the mouse or via ssh?

Comment: @user2693928 you can use `:vimgrep` or alternatively install any grep-like tool like ripgrep or silver searcher.

Answer (score 3):

There are few solutions:

### Change command

Go to `items` and then hit:

```
*Ncgn{new name}<Esc>
```

And then you can `.` through rest of the files.

#### Plugin

I have written plugin which simplifies this flow [sad.vim](https://github.com/hauleth/sad.vim) which simplifies above to:

```
siw{new name}<Esc>
```

And then you can `.` through rest of the occurrences.

### Substitute

Select function body by `vi{` and then call:

```
:'<,'>s/items/{new name}/g
```

### Language Server

If your language has Language Server that supports renames then you can use one of the many LS clients for Vim out there and use the support from there.

Answer (score 3):

The point is: in vim the movement towards the target change point happens without touching the mouse, and it can also be made via terminal through a ssh session, things which wouldn't be available using sublime. You should also consider this. I have the following map:

```
:nnoremap c* *<C-o>cgn
```

Once you hit the variable just type c* followed by the new name, Esc and dot.

For those who don't understand the above command, the built in help system will be your friend, use it figure out what `*`, `<C-o>`, `c`, `gn` all do separately and then combine your understanding.